# Specifying multiple possible criteria at one level of a multi-index cross section

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I'm newly working with a MultiIndex, and am struggling with how to get certain cross-sections of data.  Specifically, when I want to specify more than one category within an index level, but not all categories at that level.

Borrowing from pandas documentation for the data:

```
d = {'num_legs': [4, 4, 2, 2],
     'num_wings': [0, 0, 2, 2],
     'class': ['mammal', 'mammal', 'mammal', 'bird'],
     'animal': ['cat', 'dog', 'bat', 'penguin'],
     'locomotion': ['walks', 'walks', 'flies', 'walks']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df = df.set_index(['class', 'animal', 'locomotion'])
df
                           num_legs  num_wings
class  animal  locomotion
mammal cat     walks              4          0
       dog     walks              4          0
       bat     flies              2          2
bird   penguin walks              2          2
```

I'm using pandas.DataFrame.xs() to grab the data I want.  I'm able to get crossection based on one citerion  like so:
`df.xs('mammal',level = 'class')`,
and can get refine on multiple levels like so:
`df.xs(('mammal','flies'),level = ['class','locomotion'])`

Where things break down is when I want to specify, say, bat and penguin, instead of just bat.

A statement like
`df.xs((('mammal','bird')),level = ['class','class'])`
technically works, but it's looking for data that is both 'mammal' and 'bird', returning an empty dataframe.
Statements like
`df.xs((('mammal','bird')),level = 'class')`
return errors.

The .xs documentation doesn't cover this case. Is what I want possible?  Is there a better way altogether?  Any light you can shine on the subject is appreciated.

EDIT:
Answers by both respondents very helpful.  I should have mentioned that some of that data I am working with is multi-indexed at the column level, which is part of why I was looking at df.xs().  Is there a similar simple way of specifying multiple criteria at the same level for multi-indexed columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these cases, I recommend just to use `.loc`:

```py
out = df.loc[(["mammal", "bird"], slice(None), slice(None))]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
                           num_legs  num_wings
class  animal  locomotion                     
mammal cat     walks              4          0
       dog     walks              4          0
       bat     flies              2          2
bird   penguin walks              2          2
```

---

EDIT: For multi-index columns:

Initial `df`:

```
                            num_legs    num_wings   
                                   A  B         A  B
class    animal  locomotion                         
mammal   cat     walks             4  0         1  2
         dog     walks             4  0         1  2
         bat     flies             2  2         1  2
bird     penguin walks             2  2         2  2
bacteria coli    swims            -1 -1        -1 -1
```

Then:

```py
out = df.loc[(["mammal", "bird"], slice(None), "walks"), ((slice(None), "A"))]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
                          num_legs num_wings
                                 A         A
class  animal  locomotion                   
mammal cat     walks             4         1
       dog     walks             4         1
bird   penguin walks             2         2
```

Comment: Hi Andrej - appreciate your response.  Is there a similar way for multi-indexed columns?

Comment: @genbu Yes, just see my edit.

Comment: That's very clean, thanks Andrej!

Answer (score 1):

One option here is with [pyjanitor's select](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.select.select) function:

```py
df.select(rows={'animal':['bat','penguin']})

                           num_legs  num_wings
class  animal  locomotion                     
mammal bat     flies              2          2
bird   penguin walks              2          2
```

The dictionary option allows selection on MultiIndexes, where the key is either the level name or number, and the values for that key is the label/labels you wish to select (could be a slice, a list, regex, callable, str).

If you are selecting on the very first level(the outermost level), then `loc` is sufficient:

```py
df.loc[['mammal','bird']]
                           num_legs  num_wings
class  animal  locomotion                     
mammal cat     walks              4          0
       dog     walks              4          0
       bat     flies              2          2
bird   penguin walks              2          2
```

Note that if you pass a dictionary with multiple levels, it will return rows that exist in the levels, similar to a set intersection:

```py
df.select(rows={'animal':['bat','penguin'], 'locomotion': ['walks', 'flies']})
                           num_legs  num_wings
class  animal  locomotion                     
mammal bat     flies              2          2
bird   penguin walks              2          2
```

Answer (score 0):

You're slicing on first level, a `.loc` works just fine:

```
df.loc[['mammal','bird']]
```

Output:

```
                           num_legs  num_wings
class  animal  locomotion                     
mammal cat     walks              4          0
       dog     walks              4          0
       bat     flies              2          2
bird   penguin walks              2          2
```

If you want to slice on the second level, you can do a query:

```
animals = ['bat','penguin']    
df.query('animal in @animals')
```

Output:

```
                            num_legs  num_wings
classes animal  locomotion                     
mammal  bat     flies              2          2
bird    penguin walks              2          2
```

Comment: Appreciate your response, Quang Hoang.  What if I'm trying to do the same thing, but for multi-indexed columns?

Comment: **muti-indexed columns**? Do you mean something like `df.query('(animal in @animals) or (locomotion in @locomotions)')`

Comment: Andrej has a good example of what I was trying to ask about.  If you have another method
 for what he does, I'd be interested to see it as well.